# How to set record rules in ir attachment module [odoo]?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In my custom module I use `ir.attachment`.
I added a custom group .

I am trying to set the only **read access to the group members.**

```xml
<record id="ir_attachment_rule_document_access" model="ir.rule">
        <field ref="base.model_ir_attachment" name="model_id"/>
        <field name="name">Document Access</field>
        <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
        <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('lmc_crm.group_doc_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

I added the access rule in security file,but does not working.(The still **read,write,create and unlike** acces still there).

***Questions***

1)How to set access rule correctly in ir attachment.?

2)is any other method to set the only read access to particular group?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set read access using csv file.

create csv file in security/ir.model.access.xml

Then make entry in your manifest file as:

```
'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        ....
        ....
    ],
```

And the content of ir.model.access.xml should be like :

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
ir_attachment_rule_document_access,ir_attachment_rule_document_access,base.model_ir_attachment,base.group_example,1,0,0,0
```

Change the values according to your case. Hope this will address your both questions and will solve your problem.

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.I tried like but is not working  t.ir.attachment model is a transciant model, I think thats the reason behind this is not working.